# Push values one-at-a-time from a flat array into each object of an array of arrays containing objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, merge, mapping

I need to push a new property into my array of arrays of objects using the values from a flat array.

My sample arrays:

```
$users = [
    [
        (object) ["user_id" => 2]
    ],
    [
        (object) ["user_id" => 1],
        (object) ["user_id" => 1],
    ],
    [
        (object) ["user_id" => 2],
        (object) ["user_id" => 2]
    ]
];

$is_admin = [
    false,
    true,
    true,
    false,
    false
];
```

I need to write `is_admin => [boolean value]` (one at a time) into each object using the values from the second array.

Desired result:

```
[
    [
        (object) ["user_id" => 2, "is_admin" => false]
    ],
    [
        (object) ["user_id" => 1, "is_admin" => true],
        (object) ["user_id" => 1, "is_admin" => true],
    ],
    [
        (object) ["user_id" => 2, "is_admin" => false],
        (object) ["user_id" => 2, "is_admin" => false]
    ]
]
```

I do not know how to map the second array with the first array's structure. I have tried using `array_merge`, but it doesn't work properly with my data structure and requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function:

```
array_walk_recursive($users, function (&$user) use (&$is_admin) {
    $user->is_admin = current($is_admin);
    next($is_admin);
});
```

Pay attention that both `$user` and `$is_admin` passed by reference.

Also, you can use outer index variable (i.e. `$i`) to track `$is_admin` position. In such case, you need to pass (to be more precise [enclose](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)) `$i` along side with `$is_admin`, only `$i` will be passed by reference and `$is_admin` by value. I decided to take advantage of [`current`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) and [`next`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) functions, not introducing one more variable.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/22c0e50584ed8f3e40ef96a57a35ffb2a5344490).

One important thing. If your `$is_admin` array has fewer elements than `$users` arrays (they are leaves actually) `false` value will be assigned to the `is_admin` field of those users that comes after the point when there are no elements left in `$is_admin`.

Comment: After 15 years of PHP development, I've never once tried to call `array_walk_recursive()` on an array containing objects.  I was under the false impression that all "leaf nodes" were scalar type (non-iterable).  No.  Objects of any depth, no matter what they contain, are leaf nodes.  https://3v4l.org/BeEIl Mind blown.  Gotta uv your answer for teaching me something new!

Comment: For the record, this also works without any iterated function calls: https://3v4l.org/jp9Vu

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve that because the arrays are very different. Since they're of different size the `array_merge` won't work properly. Plus, the first array is multidimensional while the 2nd array is single-dimensional.

If you are 100% certain about the mapping between the indexes of array a and b you can create a loop as follows, assuming that `$array1` is the multidimensional array and $array2 is the flat array containing `true` and `false`:

```
$index = 0;
$final = array_map(function ($top_level_entry) {
  return array_map(function ($item) {
    global $index, $array2;

    $item['is_admin'] = $array2[$index];
    $index++; 
    return $item;
  }, $top_level_entry);
}, $array1);
```

or in a simpler format:

```
$index = 0;
$final = [];

foreach ($array1 as $i => $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $j => $user) {
        $user['is_admin'] = $array2[$index];
        $index++;
        $arr[$j] = $user;
    }
    $final[$i] = $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise in enjoying reference variables, I'll demonstrate assigning deep reference variables within a nested loop then looping over the `$is_admin` array to apply the values to those variables.

Admittedly, this does more loops than the other answers, but it should be said that it doesn't make any iterated function calls, does not need to maintain an incremented counter, and will not suffer if there are fewer values than reference variables (not that that is a problem with the asker's question).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6Aor5))

```
foreach ($users as &$groups) {
    foreach ($groups as $obj) {
        $obj->is_admin = &$refs[];
    }
}
foreach ($is_admin as $i => $bool) {
    $refs[$i] = $bool;
}
var_export($users);
```

Because objects in PHP have a default behavior of being modifiable by reference, you will notice that `$obj` in the nested loop is not prefixed with `&` -- it could have been for consistency, but it was not necessary.

As mentioned above the snippet, if there aren't enough elements in `$is_admin` to cover all of the reference variables declared in `$users`, then they will have a default value of `null`.